# Where is System.Linq.Expressions.FieldExpression defined?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-6.0

Observe the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var f = new Foo();
    Expression<Func<string>> x = () => f.Bar;
    MemberExpression y = (MemberExpression) x.Body;
    Expression z = y.Expression;
}

class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

When I break and observe `z`, I can see that it has a base type of [`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=net-6.0) and actual type of `System.Linq.Expressions.FieldExpression`.

[image]

The problem is that I cannot explicitly cast it as the latter:

```
System.Linq.Expressions.FieldExpression z = y.Expression;
```

I'm getting an error

> The type or namespace name 'FieldExpression' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Linq.Expressions'.

Indeed, it's nowhere to be found in [the API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions?view=net-6.0).

There are references to it out there, but the ones I've looked into have lead to broken links or similar:

https://csharpdoc.hotexamples.com/class/System.Linq.Expressions/FieldExpression
https://www.fuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Expressions/4.3.0/lib/netstandard1.6/System.Linq.Expressions.dll/System.Linq.Expressions/FieldExpression

Can someone please tell me what is going on?

Comment: Presumably it's an internal type, derived from a public type such as `MemberExpression`.

Comment: But wouldn't it give me a different error, recognizing that the type at least exists but that it's not accessible?

Comment: Are you using the .NET 6.0? For .NET Framework it is placed in System.Core.dll https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.field?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: It could do, but I don't see that it particularly *has* to. I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler's actually compiling against reference assemblies which don't contain the internal members, in which case the compiler has no way of knowing whether or not it will exist at execution time - and it shouldn't really matter. It's an implementation detail.

Comment: Ahh thanks @JonSkeet that last bit was what I was forgetting about.  I was thrown off by the lack of info out there on this elusive type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an [internal type, derived from `MemberExpression`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e95a6582fc5e003ea7f9ab4af7c5eaa868748ede/src/libraries/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Linq/Expressions/MemberExpression.cs#L88). There's nothing particularly unexpected about a public class having an internal class deriving from it.